# VBA Macro data paste multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in `Sheet1` in range `A2:D17`.

I want to copy this data & paste in various multiple sheets (count of sheets are 12).

Comment: Well, then do so. Where is the issue? What did you try so far? Please read [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). If you have no clue where to start, have a look at the Macro Recorder and do some research first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsStart As Worksheet
Set wsStart = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Not ws.Name = wsStart.Name Then
        wsStart.Range("A2:D17").Copy
        ws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```